# find the last number in list with consecutive number of numbers greater than "n"

Tags: python, list

I have a list like so

`mixed_list = [None, 1, 3, None, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, None, None, 11, 12, None, None]`

I need to find the last number in this list with consecutive number of numbers greater than `n`, which in this case is `2`. So...

Input: `mixed_list`
Output: `10`

I know I have to write a loop, but don't know how to get started after that. Can someone show me how to get started?

Comment: Why isnt the output 12 in this example?

Comment: @pault greater than 2

Comment: What help do you need? [ask]

Comment: @MoxieBall Because the `None` after `10` stop the "consecutive number" condition

Comment: I see- strictly greater than, not greater than or equal to. My bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try first to `reverse` the list and start `iterating` over it

Mark `first number` you found and start count consecutive numbers after it

`If` you got `None` before counter is greater than `n` then reset counter, mark the `next number after None` and continue iteration.

`Else`, your marked number is the answer :)

The code for this below:

```
def find_the_number(the_list, n):
    counter = 0
    possible_answer = None
    for i in reversed(the_list):
        if i is not None:
            if counter == 0:
                possible_answer = i
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 0
        if counter > n:
            return possible_answer


mixed_list = [None, 1, 3, None, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, None, None, 11, 12, None, None]
cons_number = 2
print(find_the_number(mixed_list, cons_number))
```

Comment: I was thinking of an `itertools.groupby` solution, but this is much better.

Comment: @Igor S. how come this doesn't work? `a=[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 40696.0, 43431.0, 46489.0, 48979.0, 53985.0, None, None, None, None, None, 80643.0, 87583.0, 91965.0, 105299.0, 117507.0, None, None, None, None, 0.62, 0.55, 0.43, 0.4, 0.46, None, None, None, None, 1.41, 1.31, 1.22, 1.18, 1.32, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` if i use your code, it returns `1.32` should be `53985.0`

Comment: @jason `1.32` is the last number in this list with consecutive number of numbers more then 2. Just like you asked in question. `53985.0` would be the answer if you've asked last number in first sequence which has more then 2 consecutive number

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> next((v[-1] for v in reversed(list(zip(*[mixed_list[i:] for i in range(n+1)]))) if all(v)), None)
>>> 10
```

**Explanation**

`zip(*[mixed_list[i:] for i in range(n+1)` would return n+1 consecutive numbers as a tuple

```
>>> list(zip(*[mixed_list[i:] for i in range(n+1)]))
[(None, 1, 3), (1, 3, None), (3, None, 5), (None, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 10), (8, 10, None), (10, None, None), (None, None, 11), (None, 11, 12), (11, 12, None), (12, None, None)]
```

You then reverse it

```
>>> list(reversed(list(zip(*[mixed_list[i:] for i in range(n+1)]))))
[(12, None, None), (11, 12, None), (None, 11, 12), (None, None, 11), (10, None, None), (8, 10, None), (7, 8, 10), (6, 7, 8), (5, 6, 7), (None, 5, 6), (3, None, 5), (1, 3, None), (None, 1, 3)]
```

You then filter it only when the tuple contains all numbers and return only the first number from the tuple

```
>>> [v[-1] for v in reversed(list(zip(*[mixed_list[i:] for i in range(n+1)]))) if all(v)]
[10, 8, 7]
```

All you have to do is to get the first number from the returned list :)

Comment: Sorry.. I had misunderstood the question. Thanks for the comment. I have now fixed the answer

Comment: A possible improvement- use `next(.., default=None)` instead of indexing this list: `next((v[-1] for v in reversed(list(zip(*[mixed_list[i:] for i in range(n+1)]))) if all(v)), None)` -- this will be faster and more robust to the case where no such value exists. Also please edit your answer to add more explanation!

Comment: @pault.. Thanks... Updated the answer

Comment: @Sunitha If I try the example as in the comment above for the accepted answer, your solution also returns `1.32` instead of `53985.0`

Comment: @jason. Why should it be `53985.0`. The last value with 2 non None value is `1.32`

Comment: @Sunitha it should be the last value of the first consecutive numbers with the number of consecutive numbers greater than 2. I guess the question was misunderstood and the solution just happened to work the first time. :)

Comment: That would have been easier if you have stated that clearly. Try this. `next(filter(lambda v: v[0] and not any(v[1:]), zip(*[mixed_list[i:] for i in range(n+1)])))[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.
Caveat: untested just typed here

```
minimum_consecutives = 2
mixed_list = [None, 1, 3, None, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, None, None, 11, 12, None, None]
consecutive_non_nulls = 0
last_item = None
for item in mixed_list:
   if item is not None:
       consecutive_non_nulls = consecutive_non_nulls + 1
   else:
       if consecutive_non_nulls > minimum_consecutives:
           break;
       consecutive_non_nulls = 0
   last_item = item
print(last_item)
```

Comment: OP stated last item! ex: `[ 7, 8, 10, None, None, 11, 12, 13, None]` still returns 10 should be 13.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `itertools.groupby` on the reversed list.

```
from itertools import groupby

n = 2
lst = [None, 1, 3, None, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, None, None, 11, 12, None, None]
groups = groupby(reversed(lst), lambda x: isinstance(x, int))
result = next((grplist[0] for p, grp in groups
                          for grplist in [list(grp)] 
                          if p and len(grplist) > n), None)
```

Comment: This also uses some hacky `for alias in [something_else]` syntax that will be made obsolete by the controversial new `:=` syntax Guido approved.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted the answer but realized he miss understood me, but thanks to Igor S, I modified his code and this works.

```
def get_last_number2(list, n=2):
    counter = 0
    possible_answer = None

    for i in list:
      if i is not None:
         possible_answer = i
         counter +=1
      else:
         if counter>n:
            return possible_answer
         counter = 0
```